# Visualizing what an sql statement is using

Tags: sql, graphviz, sql-parser

I have an SQL statement that uses a few tables built via another set of statements which in turn are each built by more sets of statements etc. to about 8 degrees fanning out to about 25 tables (it gets wider in the 4th degree but that level eventually starts pointing back down to the same few common sources).

I'm working on making a dot file for Graphviz that shows each statement's selected columns, and from which table each comes from. As there's case statements and functions involved, sometimes that's multiple sources per column. Once that goes a few levels it's not only a tad messy, but also hard to read or write correctly.

I've been trying to find if there's a tool that analyzes an SQL select statement and (instead of making an execution plan graph) graphs which ins go to which outs. Preferably the tool would be able to combine this with multiple layers of statements.

Does anyone know of a tool like this?

You see, searching Google for "graph an sql statement" and the like just winds up with lots of results on how to make either charts and graphs with the data from an SQL query, or something specific to graph databases. Neither are here nor there, and changing "graph" to "visualizing" hasn't helped either.

E.G.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN A.info IS NULL THEN 'Jam'
            WHEN B.inform LIKE 'N/A%' THEN 'Butter'
            WHEN A.info > 4 THEN 'Apricot'
            ELSE 'Organic'
       END AS information,
       -- More of the same
       FROM 2_KU_4_SKU AS A
       LEFT JOIN
       SKU_HOWS_ROC AS B
       ON A.fskuid = B.idfsk;
INSERT INTO 2_KU_4_SKU
       -- More case statements and other stuff but lets just say
       sku_id AS fskuid,
       short_sku_desc AS info
       FROM BASIC_SKU_TABLE_NOT_A_VIEW_TEDS_VERSION_LATEST_Q108;
INSERT INTO SKU_HOWS_ROC
       -- You guessed it
       sku_id AS idfsk, -- Because words
       sku_blurb AS inform
       FROM BASIC_SKU_TABLE_STILL_NOT_A_VIEW_BILLS_EXCELLENT_VERSION;
```

Might hopefully lead a tool to draw up something like:

[image: Rendered DOT Graph from SQL syntax parsing]

By basically parsing the above SQL and (one option) generating a DOT file for Graphviz like so:

```
Digraph G {
  fontname = "sans-serif";
  node [fontname="sans-serif",shape="record"];
  subgraph cluster0 {
    label="SELECT";
    information;
  }
  subgraph cluster1 {
     label="SKU_HOWS_ROC";
     a_idfsk [label="idfsk"];
     a_info [label="info"];
  }
  a_info -> information;

  subgraph cluster2 {
     label="2_KU_4_SKU";
     b_fskuid [label="fskuid"];
     b_inform [label="inform"];
  }
  b_inform -> information;
  b_fskuid -> a_idfsk -> b_fskuid;

  subgraph cluster3 {
     label="BASIC_SKU_TABLE_NOT_A_VIEW_TEDS_VERSION_LATEST_Q108";
     c_sku_id [label="sku_id"];
     c_short_sku_desc [label="short_sku_desc"];
  }
  c_short_sku_desc -> a_info;
  c_sku_id -> a_idfsk;

  subgraph cluster4 {
     label="BASIC_SKU_TABLE_STILL_NOT_A_VIEW_BILLS_EXCELLENT_VERSION";
     d_sku_id [label="sku_id"];
     d_sku_blurb [label="sku_blurb"];
  }
  d_sku_id -> b_fskuid;
  d_sku_blurb -> b_inform;
}
```

It would be even better if it could use fancy record type node labels to draw the tables a bit.

And, as Graphviz can generate SVG, but StackOverflow can't seem to embed it in any way that I can see, run this SVG snippet to see what it looks like (If imgur embedded above isn't working).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.39.20160727.0821 (20160727.0821)
 -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg viewBox="0.00 0.00 988.00 265.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 261)">
    <title>G</title>
    <polygon fill="white" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-261 984,-261 984,4 -4,4" />
    <g id="clust2" class="cluster">
      <title>cluster1</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="329,-91 329,-166 471,-166 471,-91 329,-91" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="400" y="-150.8" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">SKU_HOWS_ROC</text>
    </g>
    <g id="clust1" class="cluster">
      <title>cluster0</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="388,-8 388,-83 490,-83 490,-8 388,-8" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="439" y="-67.8" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">SELECT</text>
    </g>
    <g id="clust3" class="cluster">
      <title>cluster2</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="485,-91 485,-166 627,-166 627,-91 485,-91" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="556" y="-150.8" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">2_KU_4_SKU</text>
    </g>
    <g id="clust5" class="cluster">
      <title>cluster4</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="477,-174 477,-249 972,-249 972,-174 477,-174" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="724.5" y="-233.8" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">BASIC_SKU_TABLE_STILL_NOT_A_VIEW_BILLS_EXCELLENT_VERSION</text>
    </g>
    <g id="clust4" class="cluster">
      <title>cluster3</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="8,-174 8,-249 469,-249 469,-174 8,-174" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="238.5" y="-233.8" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">BASIC_SKU_TABLE_NOT_A_VIEW_TEDS_VERSION_LATEST_Q108</text>
    </g>
    <!-- information -->
    <g id="node1" class="node">
      <title>information</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="396.373,-16.5 396.373,-52.5 481.627,-52.5 481.627,-16.5 396.373,-16.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="439" y="-30.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">information</text>
    </g>
    <!-- a_idfsk -->
    <g id="node2" class="node">
      <title>a_idfsk</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="409,-99.5 409,-135.5 463,-135.5 463,-99.5 409,-99.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="435.893" y="-113.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">idfsk</text>
    </g>
    <!-- b_fskuid -->
    <g id="node4" class="node">
      <title>b_fskuid</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="565,-99.5 565,-135.5 619,-135.5 619,-99.5 565,-99.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="591.786" y="-113.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">fskuid</text>
    </g>
    <!-- a_idfsk&#45;&gt;b_fskuid -->
    <g id="edge4" class="edge">
      <title>a_idfsk&#45;&gt;b_fskuid</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M446.616,-135.503C455.979,-149.063 471.07,-165.983 490,-170 504.373,-173.05 544.531,-175.185 556,-166 563.413,-160.064 570.086,-152.258 575.615,-144.648" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="578.818,-146.164 581.557,-135.929 573.033,-142.222 578.818,-146.164" />
    </g>
    <!-- a_info -->
    <g id="node3" class="node">
      <title>a_info</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="337,-99.5 337,-135.5 391,-135.5 391,-99.5 337,-99.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="363.786" y="-113.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">info</text>
    </g>
    <!-- a_info&#45;&gt;information -->
    <g id="edge1" class="edge">
      <title>a_info&#45;&gt;information</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M380.274,-99.4902C390.62,-88.0401 404.181,-73.0328 415.665,-60.3245" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="418.391,-62.5274 422.499,-52.7612 413.198,-57.8343 418.391,-62.5274" />
    </g>
    <!-- b_fskuid&#45;&gt;a_idfsk -->
    <g id="edge3" class="edge">
      <title>b_fskuid&#45;&gt;a_idfsk</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M581.557,-135.929C575.195,-145.863 566.313,-157.741 556,-166 544.531,-175.185 504.373,-173.05 490,-170 474.767,-166.767 462.021,-155.18 452.744,-143.712" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="455.403,-141.423 446.616,-135.503 449.793,-145.61 455.403,-141.423" />
    </g>
    <!-- b_inform -->
    <g id="node5" class="node">
      <title>b_inform</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="492.552,-99.5 492.552,-135.5 547.448,-135.5 547.448,-99.5 492.552,-99.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="520" y="-113.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">inform</text>
    </g>
    <!-- b_inform&#45;&gt;information -->
    <g id="edge2" class="edge">
      <title>b_inform&#45;&gt;information</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M502.424,-99.4902C491.145,-87.9321 476.328,-72.7493 463.852,-59.9655" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="466.31,-57.4735 456.821,-52.7612 461.301,-62.3626 466.31,-57.4735" />
    </g>
    <!-- c_sku_id -->
    <g id="node6" class="node">
      <title>c_sku_id</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="404.766,-182.5 404.766,-218.5 461.234,-218.5 461.234,-182.5 404.766,-182.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="433" y="-196.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">sku_id</text>
    </g>
    <!-- c_sku_id&#45;&gt;a_idfsk -->
    <g id="edge6" class="edge">
      <title>c_sku_id&#45;&gt;a_idfsk</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M433.651,-182.49C434.037,-171.796 434.536,-157.999 434.975,-145.871" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="438.476,-145.881 435.34,-135.761 431.481,-145.628 438.476,-145.881" />
    </g>
    <!-- c_short_sku_desc -->
    <g id="node7" class="node">
      <title>c_short_sku_desc</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="272.973,-182.5 272.973,-218.5 387.027,-218.5 387.027,-182.5 272.973,-182.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="330" y="-196.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">short_sku_desc</text>
    </g>
    <!-- c_short_sku_desc&#45;&gt;a_info -->
    <g id="edge5" class="edge">
      <title>c_short_sku_desc&#45;&gt;a_info</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M337.377,-182.49C341.847,-171.58 347.639,-157.441 352.679,-145.138" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="355.968,-146.342 356.519,-135.761 349.49,-143.688 355.968,-146.342" />
    </g>
    <!-- d_sku_id -->
    <g id="node8" class="node">
      <title>d_sku_id</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="579.766,-182.5 579.766,-218.5 636.234,-218.5 636.234,-182.5 579.766,-182.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="608" y="-196.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">sku_id</text>
    </g>
    <!-- d_sku_id&#45;&gt;b_fskuid -->
    <g id="edge7" class="edge">
      <title>d_sku_id&#45;&gt;b_fskuid</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M604.528,-182.49C602.467,-171.796 599.807,-157.999 597.469,-145.871" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="600.85,-144.918 595.52,-135.761 593.976,-146.243 600.85,-144.918" />
    </g>
    <!-- d_sku_blurb -->
    <g id="node9" class="node">
      <title>d_sku_blurb</title>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="484.648,-182.5 484.648,-218.5 561.352,-218.5 561.352,-182.5 484.648,-182.5" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="523" y="-196.3" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14.00">sku_blurb</text>
    </g>
    <!-- d_sku_blurb&#45;&gt;b_inform -->
    <g id="edge8" class="edge">
      <title>d_sku_blurb&#45;&gt;b_inform</title>
      <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M522.349,-182.49C521.963,-171.796 521.464,-157.999 521.025,-145.871" />
      <polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="524.519,-145.628 520.66,-135.761 517.524,-145.881 524.519,-145.628" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is more of a data flow or data lineage diagram. You might want to search on that. Note that if you build a data flow in a visual tool like SSIS, it's very difficult to represent a neat data flow in a single 'surface' like that, because not only is there a data flow aspect, there is an 'ordered steps' aspect - this data flow runs before that data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the Visual Explain functionality found in MySQL Workbench. I haven't personally used it but it looks like it may provide better insight than the standard EXPLAIN command.  Take a look at this link, and good luck!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html